The library path of gold linker (ld.gold)

How to set library search path through environment variables? (since I'm using bazel)
How to print library search path used by ld.gold (so I can check if I set it correctly)

Context:
I'm compiling a project using bazel, and the error message is:
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lresolv_wrapper
Here is the output of ldconfig:
➜  /tmp ldconfig -p | grep resolv_wrapper
    libresolv_wrapper.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /home/xiaochencui/local/libresolv_wrapper/lib/libresolv_wrapper.so.0
    libresolv_wrapper.so (libc6,x86-64) => /home/xiaochencui/local/libresolv_wrapper/lib/libresolv_wrapper.so

Note:

I have read this page but it doesn't help:
'LD' can't find library to link, even though 'ldconfig -v' lists the file
I know we can add library search path by --library-path arg, but I'm not using ld.gold directly.

